# Is there a way to avoid repetitive code in the following switch statement?

Tags: c#

I have the following method, which is called every time the user clicks a checkbox within a `Datagrid`. Each column within this `Datagrid` has a box in its header, which checks/unchecks all child checkboxes in the respective column. This header checkbox will be updated according to the child checkboxes by the method.

My problem is that there is a lot of repetitive code in it since we do the same operation for each property (column) based on the checkbox that was clicked.

Here is the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the Columnsheadercheckbox based on the individual checkbox values of the respective filter
    /// </summary>
    private void SetHeaderCheckbox(string filterProperty = null)
    {
        if (GridData.Count == 0) return;
        var filter = GridData[0];
        DataGridDropdownProperty found;
        if (filterProperty == null) filterProperty = "all";
        switch (filterProperty)
        {
            case "SuperImpose":
                found = GridData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.SplitOver != filter.SplitOver);
                if (found == null)
                {
                    SuperimposeHeaderCheckbox = filter.SplitOver;
                }
                else
                {
                    SuperimposeHeaderCheckbox = null;
                }
                break;
            case "Normalize":
                found = GridData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ToNormalize != filter.ToNormalize);
                if (found == null)
                {
                    NormalizeByHeaderCheckbox = filter.ToNormalize;
                }
                else
                {
                    NormalizeByHeaderCheckbox = null;
                }
                break;
            case "Legend":
                found = GridData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ToLegend != filter.ToLegend);
                if (found == null)
                {
                    LegendHeaderCheckbox = filter.ToLegend;
                }
                else
                {
                    LegendHeaderCheckbox = null;
                }
                break;
            case "all":
                // Superimpose
                found = GridData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.SplitOver != filter.SplitOver);
                if (found == null)
                {
                    SuperimposeHeaderCheckbox = filter.SplitOver;
                }
                else
                {
                    SuperimposeHeaderCheckbox = null;
                }
                // Normalize
                found = GridData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ToNormalize != filter.ToNormalize);
                if (found == null)
                {
                    NormalizeByHeaderCheckbox = filter.ToNormalize;
                }
                else
                {
                    NormalizeByHeaderCheckbox = null;
                }
                // Legend
                found = GridData.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ToLegend != filter.ToLegend);
                if (found == null)
                {
                    LegendHeaderCheckbox = filter.ToLegend;
                }
                else
                {
                    LegendHeaderCheckbox = null;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

My question is, if this kind of code is 'OK' or if it is, this is terrible practice, and there should be a more elegant way around it. (btw. Ignore the hardcoded strings. This is to illustrate the example)

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [**How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions**](https://CodeReview.Meta.StackExchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace the `if-else` statements under each case with inline if statements. You can remove the `if-else` repetitions. For example..

   ```
   SuperimposeHeaderCheckbox = found ? null : filter.SplitOver;
   ```
2. You can use turn `filterProperty` into an enumeration (instead of a string).

   ```
   enum flags {SuperImpose=1, Normalize=2, Legend=4, all=7};
   ```
3. Finally, replace the `switch-case` statement with simple `if` statements. You can remove the repetitions for the case `all`.

   ```
   if (filterProperty & flags.SuperImpose) {
    // your code here
   }
   if (filterProperty & flags.Normalize) {
    // your code here
   }
   if (filterProperty & flags.Legend) {
    // your code here
   }
   // No need for a fourth if statement.
   ```
4. If you furthur want to reduce the number of the above `if` statements, you can map the properties in `filter` to the values in the enumeration and loop through the map.

Comment: Thanks, for the tipp, but with this it will still be repeating code for each case statement.

Comment: @Roland Deschain, I am adding more to my answer, give me some time.

Comment: Inline statements are *not* an improvement over a switch statement.

Comment: @shards yes, sorry...all your tips are nice to tidy up the code a bit and make it more readable, but my question was about the repetitiveness of the code itself. But it seems there is no way around doing the same statement for each of the filter properties...

Comment: @RolandDeschain of course there is a way. You just have to define all the properties and put them in a dictionary. Let it be the filter holding a dictionary of string to property value directly. Or let it be a dictionary of string to property getter callback, held by the class in question.

Comment: @slepic just googled a bit around and, yes, this seems to be what I'm looking for!

Comment: `found ? filter.SplitOver : null` It should be inverted. OP's code fills in the value when `found == null`

Comment: @Flater, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can always avoid repeating code by abstracting the general parts.

For example, your switch statement could be abstracted with the following code (assumed some types that are not declared in your question):

```
private interface IChecker
{
    void Apply(GridData gridData);
    bool CanApply(string filterPropertyName);
}

private class Checker<TFilterProperty> : IChecker
{
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly Func<Filter, TFilterProperty> filterSelector;
    private readonly Func<GridRow, TFilterProperty> gridRowSelector;
    private readonly Action<TFilterProperty> filterSetter;

    public Checker(
        string name, 
        Func<Filter, TFilterProperty> filterSelector, 
        Func<GridRow, TFilterProperty> gridRowSelector,
        Action<TFilterProperty> filterSetter)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.filterSelector = filterSelector;
        this.gridRowSelector = gridRowSelector;
        this.filterSetter = filterSetter;
    }

    public void Apply(GridData gridData)
    {
        var filter = GridData[0];
        var filterValue = filterSelector(filter);
        var found = GridData.FirstOrDefault(f => gridRowSelector(f) != filterValue);
        var valueToSet = found == null ? filterValue : null;
        this.filterSetter(valueToSet);
    }

    public bool CanApply(string filterPropertyName) => filterPropertyName == "all" || filterPropertyName == this.name;
}

private void SetHeaderCheckbox(string filterProperty = null)
{
    if (GridData.Count == 0) return;

    if (filterProperty == null) filterProperty = "all";

    var checkers = new IChecker[]
    {
        new Checker("SuperImpose", f => f.SplitOver, f => f.SplitOver, v => this.SuperimposeHeaderCheckbox = value),
        new Checker("Normalize", f => f.ToNormalize, f => f.ToNormalize, v => this.NormalizeByHeaderCheckbox = value),
        new Checker("Legend", f => f.ToLegend, f => f.ToLegend, v => this.LegendHeaderCheckbox = value),
    }

    foreach (var checker in checkers.Where(c => c.CanApply(filterProperty))
    {
        checker.Apply(GridData);
    }
}
```

Whether the abstracted code is more readable / maintainable is another question that depends on the concrete use case :)

Note that the code above is just an untested example that illustrates the abstraction of common parts. There may be better abstractions with less delegates in your case ;)